# Find The limit Of $a_n=\frac{1}{n^2}\cdot\sum_{k=1}^{n}[kx]$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Find The Limit Of $$a_n=\frac{1}{n^2}\cdot\sum_{k=1}^{n}[kx]$$

Where $[a]:=max\{k\in \mathbb{Z}:k\leq a\}$ for $a\in \mathbb{R}$

For any $x\in \mathbb{R}$ there is $z\in \mathbb{Z}$ $$\frac{n(1+n)}{2}*-(z+1)\leq\sum_{k=1}^{n}[kx]= \frac{k(1+n)}{2}[x]\leq \frac{n(1+n)}{2}(z)$$

Therefore:

$$\frac{-z-1}{2}\leftarrow\frac{1}{n^2}*\frac{n(1+n)}{2}*-(z+1)\leq \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}[kx]\leq \frac{1}{n^2}*\frac{n(1+n)}{2}*(z)\to\frac{z}{2}$$

How can I continue from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how did you get into that state, [but](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Equivalences)
$$x-1<\left \lfloor  x\right \rfloor \leq x$$
thus
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(kx-1\right)<\sum_{k=1}^{n}[kx]\leq \sum_{k=1}^{n}kx \iff\\
x\cdot\frac{n(n+1)}{2}-n<\sum_{k=1}^{n}[kx]\leq x\cdot\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
and
$$x\cdot\frac{n(n+1)}{2n^2}-\frac{1}{n}<\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}[kx]\leq x\cdot\frac{n(n+1)}{2n^2}\iff \\
\frac{x}{2}\cdot\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)-\frac{1}{n}<\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}[kx]\leq \frac{x}{2}\cdot\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$$
As aresult, by [squeezing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem)
$$\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}[kx] \to \frac{x}{2}, n\to\infty$$